# Is 새끼 고양이 입 used as a term related to not liking spicy or hot (temperature) food?

Tags: korean-to-english

I had an acquaintance who told me that Korean has a nice term for not being able to tolerate hot food. I can't eat hot food because the spice burns, but I also can't drink hot drinks, because there is too much heat.

They said that the term/word translated to "kitten mouth" in English. I did an English-to-Korean, and then put 새끼 고양이 입 into Korean-to-English and got the same phrase back. But a search of 새끼 고양이 입 doesn't locate any usage. I got the impression that the usage referred specifically to my mouth, and not to me. For example, instead of saying "that is too hot" I would say something like - and this is Google Translate - "나는 새끼 고양이 입이".

Is this a term that is used?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I've never heard that kind of idioms since I've been Korea for 20 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess they meant `cat tongue` which is originally a Japanese expression and a widespread also in South Korea.

In Korean it either reads as `고양이 혀` or `네코지타`.

I could find the definition from a Japanese-Korean dictionary.

> ねこじた [猫舌]
>
> 명사
>
> 1. 뜨거운 음식을 잘 먹지 못하는 일; 또, 그런 사람.

https://ja.dict.naver.com/#/entry/jako/c4653ada92e6435aa8d237478a5498d7

There's also a newspaper article from 1995 describing what it means and how it is used.

> 여러분이 아시는지 모르겠지만 네꼬는 뜨거운 걸 전혀 먹지 못한다. 개는 뜨거운 국물에 밥을 말아주더라도 대충대충 챙겨 먹는다. 네꼬는 혀를 살짝 댔다가도 기겁을 하고 물러나 다 식을때까지 악전고투를 한다.
>
> 배가 고파 먹고싶어 죽겠는데 뜨거워 발을 동동 구르는 그 모습을 보고 있으면 우습기도 하고 불쌍하기도 하다.
>
> 네꼬처럼 뜨거운 걸 잘 못먹는 사람이 많다.
>
> 커피도 후후 불면서 마셔야 하고 뜨거운 국물은 먹을 엄두도 내지 못한다.
>
> 그런 사람을 네꼬지타라고 한다. 모두 같이 라면을 먹는다 치자. 다른 사람들은 국수 다 먹고 국물까지 마셨는데 네꼬지타들은 아직도 국물을 피해 필사적으로 국수를 건져 먹고 있다.
>
> 그러면서 「미안합니다. 저는 고양이 혀라서요」 - 스미마생. 와따시네꼬지타나 몬데스까라(すみません.私,猫舌な もんですから)하며 연방 사과하고 있을 것이다.
>
> 猫舌(ねこじた) 고양이 혀(뜨거운 걸 잘 못먹는 사람)

https://mnews.joins.com/amparticle/3136346

Some actual use cases:

> 나처럼 뜨거운거 극악으로 못먹는사람 있음?
> 뜨거운거 먹을수 있긴 한데
> 뜨거운거 입에 넣으면  입 식히려고 계속 찬물마심
> 근데 이 정도가 심해서 밥한입 물한모금임 밥 한번 먹으면 업소용 물병 반병은 마시는듯

> 완전 **고양이 혀**네

> 매운거도 못먹는거 봐서 전생에 고양이였나봄 ㅋㅎㅎ

https://tgd.kr/s/funzinnu/10662675

> 국 그릇이나 고기 뜯을 때 저 뜨거운걸 어찌 만지지? 하는 생각을 엄청 자주 합니다. 저는 뜨거운 것도 잘 못 마시고요 (**고양이 혀**라고 하더라구요), 근데 찬 것도 잘 못 만지고 먹어요. 그냥 일년 내내 미지근하게 삽니다 ㅜㅜ

https://pgr21.com/qna/84935

> **평소에 뜨거운 것을 못먹는 다는 뜻으로** **고양이 혀**라는 표현을 썼는데 갑자기 이 표현은 일본에서 온 거 같다는 느낌이 들었습니다. 고양이 혀라는 표현은 우리나라 표현이 맞나요?

https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=90585

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that expression is common in Korean - I don't think I've ever heard of it.

Comment: 생각해 보면 남녀노소 다 쓰는 말은 아닌 거 같고, 저는 2000년대 초중반부터 이런 표현을 종종 들었는데 주로 젊은/어린 여자들이 사용합니다. 뜨거운 차나 음식을 홀짝거리고 있는 사람을 비유해서 놀려 먹을 때 쓰는 표현입니다.

Comment: Thank you, her partner is Japanese, but she specifically said Korean phrase. The link to a Japanese expression makes sense, particularly in this context. And yes, I do blow on hot soup!

Comment: If I hear someone using it, I would think that they studied Japanese language and using it all the time. There's some Koreans (usually anime fans) who uses Japanese expressions in Korean. Of course many Koreans can't understand that and some even think that they are weird.

Comment: 제가 적은 댓글이 삭제돼서 추가 의견을 다시 씁니다. 위 Absol님이 다신 댓글의 의도가 불순하다는 점은 차치하고, 제가 답변으로 소개한 표현이 굳이 일본어를 공부했거나 일본 애니메이션 팬이 아닌 보통 사람이라도 대화 중에 자연스럽게 쓸 수 있는 말이고 실례로도 그렇다는 것은 사실이기 때문에 바로잡고 넘어가려고 합니다. 본문 마지막에 링크 건 예시 셋이 증명하고자 하는 바가 그 점인데도 불구하고 '일본 애니메이션 팬이나 쓰는 말이다' 이런 식으로 해석을 하는 것은 큰 왜곡이고 편견 가득한 의견이라는 말입니다. 가령 뜨거운 음식에 데일 때 '완전 고양이 혀네' 이렇게 말 들었으면, 보통 사람들이라면 그렇게도 비유하는구나 생각하고 그냥 넘어갑니다. 그 정도로 자연스러운 표현이고 듣자마자 일본말이라고 느낄 수는 없습니다. 전 일본 애니메이션 팬도 아니고 일본과 조금도 관계가 없고, 마찬가지로 일본과 관계 없는 사람들이 이런 표현을 쓰는 것을 자주 들었습니다.

Comment: If you search google with keyword "고양이 혀" -일본어, (so excluding the articles which explains the word 猫舌), you only get 60k results. Most of them are literally about cat's tongue, so there are very few instances of Koreans actually using that expression. Also see this link: 
https://kin.naver.com/qna/detail.nhn?d1id=13&dirId=13050202&docId=49838040&qb=6rOg7JaR7J207ZiA&enc=utf8&section=kin&rank=1&search_sort=0&spq=0 
You can see several people being not able to figure out the meaning of this word.I wouldn't say such expression is "being used naturally" by Koreans.

Comment: '고양이 혀'가 자연스러운 표현이라는 의견 역시 편견입니다. 그런 상황에 굳이 '고양이'를 쓸 이유가 없기 때문입니다(다른 동물은 안 그렇습니까?). Absol 님 댓글을 "일본 애니메이션 팬**이나** 쓰는 말이다."라고 이해하셨는데 저분 의견은 "내가 그 말을 듣는다면 나는 화자가 일본어를 학습해서 그 표현을 계속 사용했다고 생각하겠다."입니다. 어찌하여 "우리말로 일본 표현을 쓰는 한국인들(보통 애니매이션 팬들)이 좀 있다."를 그리 해석하시는지 모르겠으나, 본인이 타국과 관계가 없다고 해도 타인과 대화하면서 그런 표현에 익숙해질 수는 있다는 점을 간과하여서는 안 됩니다. '들은 적이 없는 표현'이라는 댓글이 여기에 있고 타 온라인 커뮤니티에서도 유사 댓글을 많이 찾을 수 있는 데다가 해당 표현이 우리말샘에 등재된 말도 아니니 작성자분께서 쓰신 "widespread also in South Korea"는 과장으로 보입니다.

Comment: 저나 다른 분이 예시로 링크 건 글을 읽어 보세요. 아무리 몰라도 최소한 '사람들이 그런 표현도 쓰더라' 정도의 인지도는 충분히 있다는 사실이 드러납니다. 나는 그만큼이면 이미 널리 쓰인다고 말하기에 충분한 것이고 `widespread`도 거짓이 아니라고 생각합니다. '암은 한국에서 흔한 질병이다.'라고 말하기 위해선 전국민의 50% 이상이 암 환자여야만 한다 뭐 이런 규칙이라도 누가 어디 정해 놨던가요? 그리고 어법상 어색하지도 않고 자연스럽고 자연스럽게 쓰는 말이고 고양이 혀를 처음 들은 사람들의 반응도 '이걸 고양이에도 비유하는구나' 내지는 '왜 고양이 혀에 빗대었을까' 같은 것이지 듣자마자 '어이쿠, 이 놈은 일본놈이겠거니~!' 절대 이러지 않는단 말입니다. 한일 문화 개방이 있은지 20년이 지났는데 일본에서 쓰는 말을 당연히 한국에서도 차용해서 많이 쓰겠죠. 저는 제가 올바른 견해를 적었다고 생각합니다. 생트집 잡지 마십시다.

Comment: 작성자 본인이 아닌 그 누가 그 의도를 풀이해서 해석해 줄 수 있는지는 모르겠으나 이 댓글의 의도가 저는 멸시로밖에는 보이지 않습니다. If I hear someone using it, I would think that they studied Japanese language and using it all the time. There's some Koreans (usually anime fans) who uses Japanese expressions in Korean. Of course many Koreans can't understand that and some even think that they are weird. – Absol Oct 21 at 4:47

Comment: "처음 듣는다."라는 글들이 "사람들이 그런 표현도 쓰더라."나 "그런 표현이 이미 널리 쓰인다."로 해석될 수 있습니까? '고양이 혀'가 널리 퍼진 말이면 열 명 중 여덟 명 이상이 쓰는 유튜브에서 제목으로 종종 쓰였어야 하는 것 아닙니까? 물론 사람마다 생각이 다르니 *widespread* 관련하여 작성자분 의견을 존중하겠으나 동의는 하지 않겠습니다. 해당 표현이 남녀노소 다 아는 표현이 아닌 것은 본인도 인정하셨습니다. // 제가 근거를 들어 지적을 하였는데 '생트집'이라고 하신 점은 납득이 되지 않습니다. '절대'라는 말씀도 하셨는데 그 기준은 누가 정하였습니까? 신문에 일본어로 소개된 적이 있는 표현이기도 하니 '일본' 생각이 나는 사람이 있을 것입니다. 작성하신 댓글들로 봐서는 Coconut 님께서 외려 일본 애니메이션 팬을 혐오하고 계십니다. 본인을 일본 애니메이션 팬 따위로 취급하는 것이냐는 말씀을 하신 것처럼 들리기 때문입니다. I *disagree* that 고양이 혀 is widespread in South Korea; a larger portion of people will not understand that expression.

Comment: 어느 누가 한국어조차도 똑바로 읽고 쓰지 못하는 주제에 다른 사람을 가르치려 들 수 있겠습니까. 스택 익스체인지에 와서 이제 가나다라 배우고 있는 한국어 초보자들 상대로 전문가질이나 하겠죠. 처음에 jick의 댓글 보고 기분 좋게 수용했는데, 그 밑에 한 명 한 술 더 떠보고 싶었는지 말도 안 되는 시나리오 짜붙여서 선 넘고 다른 누구는 심지어 그걸 두둔하고 계시네요. jick 댓글에 업보트 하나 찍어 주고 그냥 넘어갔으면 좋았을 거 같은데요. 사람 머저리 취급하는 것도 정도껏이어야 농담으로 받아 준답니다. :D